# MIPS register content

Tags: assembly, mips

We run code from adress **8002000 to 80020028** and the question is what is inside register **$18** at when we are at the end. I think there might be **0x0E** but I am really not sure how i got to this answer anymore. Anyone can explain?

And if we start at 80020000 and follow the instructions as written can an exception occur? If yes when can it occur?

```
8001FFF8    NOP 
8001FFFC    NOP
80020000    LUI     $16, 0x8002
80020004    ADDIU   $16, $16, 0x30
80020008    ADDI    $17, $00, 0x3
8002000c    SLL     $17, $17, 0x2
80020010    LW      $18, 0x4 ($16)
80020014    LW      $19, 0x0 ($16)
80020018    SW      $18, 0x8 ($16)
8002001C    NOP
80020020    ADD     $18, $18, $17
80020024    NOP
80020028    NOP
8002002C    NOP
80020030    ???
80020034    SRL     $00, $00, 0
80020038    SRA     $00, $00, 0
8002003C    SLLV    $00, $00, $00
80020040    NOP
80020044    NOP
```

Comment: it should load the immediate operand in the first 16 bits of the register so I guess it should be 0x80020000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
8001FFF8    NOP 
8001FFFC    NOP
80020000    LUI     $16, 0x8002
80020004    ADDIU   $16, $16, 0x30
```

$16 = 0x80020030

```
80020008    ADDI    $17, $00, 0x3
8002000c    SLL     $17, $17, 0x2
```

$17 = 12      ( 3 << 2 )

```
80020010    LW      $18, 0x4 ($16)
```

$18 = 0x2    ( load value from 80020034 which disassembled is srl $0,$0,0 -> 0x2 )

```
80020014    LW      $19, 0x0 ($16)
```

$19 = ???      ( value under 0x80020030 not known )

```
80020018    SW      $18, 0x8 ($16)
```

store under 0x80020038  (0x2)

```
8002001C    NOP
80020020    ADD     $18, $18, $17
```

$18 = 0xE    ( 0x2 + 12 )

```
80020024    NOP
80020028    NOP
```

$18 = 0xE     ( nops don't change anything )

```
8002002C    NOP
80020030    ???
80020034    SRL     $00, $00, 0
80020038    SRA     $00, $00, 0
8002003C    SLLV    $00, $00, $00
80020040    NOP
80020044    NOP
```

Exception in this code is possible (  I could miss something ):

- at 80020018 sw instruction, if address if this fragment of memory is write-protected ( segmentation fault )
- at 80020030 if executing code continues and execute this  address ( illegal instruction )
- at 80020010 if this fragment of memory is read-protected (very unlikely) ( segmentation fault )
- at 80020000 if this fragment of memory is non-executable ( unlikely ) ( segmentation fault )
- if addresses visible in this dump are not these visible by process which executes this code.. - hard to say without knowing environment and how this dump was got.